# SQL: Deleting sorted rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following table:

```
item_id : int
image_id : int
position : int
```

For each PRIMARY KEY tuple (item_id, image_id) there is a unique position, which is sorted with no holes:

```
item_id image_id position
1       10       0 
1       21       1 
1       17       2 
1       113      3
```

What would be the best way for removing (1, 21) so that it stay correctly sorted? I am looking for the simplest SQL query possible.

Comment: So if i get it correctly: if (1,21) would be deleted, (17,2) must become (17,1) and (113,3) should become (133,2), etc?

Comment: If you mean what Rik_S is saying, then that design is not very desirable. The column `position` doesnt't have any use, you could just look at the row index.

Comment: Rik_S: true. Tea: How would you insert a new row on the second place?

Comment: You can't add a new record specifically between two existing records. The mysql server will display them in order of their Primary Keys (unless you use ORDER BY on your sql statements). So, if you want to remove or place a new record, you have to change the `position` field of the other records accordingly.

Comment: Of course, that is why I need the position.

Answer (score 0):

you can create trigger which will update your table:

This trigger will be fired up and will update position column after you delete any row:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER trigName ON TableName
 AFTER DELETE 

 AS
    UPDATE T 
    SET t.position = n.position 
    FROM TableName AS T
    INNER JOIN (SELECT  itemID,imageID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) - 1 as Position FROM TableName) as N ON t.itemID = n.itemID AND t.imageID = n.ImageID
GO
```